# Fix bootstrap differences betwen GlyphIcon and FontAwesome

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, glyphicons

I currently trying to create a nice navbar menu using bootstrap web framework and I have to use both font family icons GlyphIcon and FontAwesome but my problem is that the icons are not created with the same size and I have differences between FontAwesome and GlyphIcons, does someone know a fix for this problem ?

**[Here is a small fiddle, hover over menu to see the differences:](http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/256/)**

```
.navbar-default{background:#B9DBF7; border-color: #000;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{font-size: 20px;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li >a:hover{ padding-bottom: 12px; border-bottom:4px solid red;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their prefixes `("fa" and "glyphicon")` to set them a same size because there is a difference by default between glyphicon and fontawesome so try this:

> ```
> Less:
> ```

```
  .navbar-nav {
    > li > a {
      [class*="fa-"], [class*="glyphicon-"]{
          font-size:16px;
      }

 //your custom less/css

      &:hover,
      &:focus {

 //your custom less/css
      }
    }
}
```

> which will compile something like in css:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a [class*="fa-"],
.navbar-nav > li > a [class*="glyphicon-"] {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can start with setting line-height to some fixed size:

```
body{padding:40px;}

.navbar-default{background:#B9DBF7; border-color: #000;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{font-size: 20px; padding-top: 4px; padding-bottom: 4px; line-height: 42px;}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li >a:hover{ padding-bottom: 0; border-bottom:4px solid red;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZurAk/257/